# Getting the ID of user controls gridview

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, user-controls

I have multiple check box on the asp.net page along with user control. I need to enable and disable user control's gridview and some other controls using jquery based on some checkboxes.

How to get the user controls control?

Comment: Want to show the rendered html?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose if the grid view id is grv

simple access using

```
$('#grv')
```

Answer (score 0):

Well with the html that you've given, if you have checkboxes inside a grid that you wish to disable -

Assume the id of the `gridview` is `grdView`

`$("#grdView").children(":checkbox").prop("disabled",true);`

If it's textboxes then,

`$("#grdView").children("input[type='text']").prop("disabled",true);`

Comment: Checkbox is in the aspx page.  Gridview is in user control.